# Parsing 'selectedValue' out of RadDropDownList using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, telerik, rad-controls

The title says what I'm trying to do.

I've got a control ('#dropdown') that has this as is its value:

```
value="{"enabled":true,"logEntries":[],"selectedIndex":8,"selectedText":"Option2","selectedValue":"250"}"
```

I'm trying to pull "250" from the "selectedValue" field.

Unfortunately, doing $('#dropdown').val gives me the above string as its value.

Is there a way to pull just the "selectedValue", or is this something I will have to parse through?

Hoping to find out here before I go about doing a parse method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using some js plugin in your dropdownlist?
This type of value is odd to me

Comment: @MárcioGonzalez no this is Telerik RadDropDownList value... this is the string received when assigning ($'#dropdown').val to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [viewing this Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-posted-value), it turns out that "selectedValue" cannot be extracted a single value. The solution, instead, was to use a regular ASP dropdownlist to produce the value I need.